# CSS/jQuery: make the icon blink

Tags: jquery, css

I remember doing some css learning where i learned to make text-decoration: blink, and the text started blinking.

Now i have a icon,

```
.iconPM{
background: url(../images/icons/mail_16x16.png) no-repeat;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
border: none;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Wonder if i can make this blink, either by simple css or jquery if required. Or maybe any other nice effects available in jquery recommended

Comment: It's not a question of whether you can, it's a question of whether you should :P

Comment: You can use a JQuery Blink plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blink

Comment: You can use `<blink></blink>` tags.  :-P

Comment: @Rocket: **I have no idea what that is, moving on...** :P

Comment: @BoltClock could you do deeper in the "should", why not? I would like to mark the icon somehow if the user has a new PM(in this case), either light it up, blink (both) or something third...suggestion?

Answer (score 25):

A simple jquery like this would do it:

```
function blink(){
    $('.iconPM').delay(100).fadeTo(100,0.5).delay(100).fadeTo(100,1, blink);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    blink();
});
```

Comment: Except, I should warn you, in IE it will look horrible if you don't convert your PNG icon into a GIF or something like that... or you can just choose to not care about IE.

Answer (score 17):

CSS animations are [fairly well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) now, so I thought I'd share a CSS only answer.

```css
.iconPM {
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephenhutchings/typicons.font/493867748439a8e1ac3b92e275221f359577bd91/src/png-24px/mail.png) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  display:inline-block;
  
  animation: blink 2s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from, to { opacity: 1 }
  50% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<span class="iconPM"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

CSS:

```
.iconPM.no-image{ background:none; }
```

JS:

```
var toggleClassFcn = function(){$(".iconPM").toggleClass("no-image");}
setInterval(toggleClassFcn, 300);
```

Just be careful as with any other animations on the page. It will consume thread on the page.

Comment: CSS should be `.iconPM.no-image{ background:none; }`

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible with CSS alone.

jQuery itself does not have predefined animations but provides [methods to easily animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) it yourself.

For a blink-like:

```
function t1(){
  jQuery(".iconPM").animate({ 
    opacity: 0,
  }, 1000 );
}
function t2(){
  jQuery(".iconPM").animate({ 
    opacity: 0,
  }, 1000 );
}
runT1 = true;
function rr() {
  if (runT1) {
    t1();
  } else {
    t2();
  }
  // toggle between 2 fns
  runT1 = !runT1;
  setTimeout("rr()", 500);
}
rr();
```